# java multi threading..thread communicating each other

Tags: java, multithreading

My Question is related to the Working of two thread at a time,suppose one thread write a file and release the resource to another thread for reading the same file and vice versa.But the communication is not happening properly. here is the code snippet

**Thread 1**

```
        public void run() {
            for(int i=1;i<10;i++) {
                System.out.println(i+"i");
                System.out.println("writing the  file");
                try {
                    synchronized (new A()) {
                        wait();
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
```

**Thread 2**

```
        public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
            for(int j=1;j<10;j++) {
                System.out.println(j+"j");
                System.out.println("reading the file");
                synchronized (new B()) {
                    notifyAll();    
                }
            }
```

Comment: Questions of the form "here's my code, please tell me what's wrong" are generally off-topic unless you can identify a specific problem more precisely.  Please visit the [help] and especially read [ask].

Comment: This link might help you. https://dzone.com/articles/producer-consumer-pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

synchronization happens on a particular monitor object.

In your code you create new monitors for each synchronization block, with the new operator.

So you will never lock the access to this fragment of code because no other monitor can be taken by another thread.

Comment: This is not a solution. Is simply a an explanation of your biggest error. Take a look at the pattern producer consumer as stated in the comment of Sneh

Answer (score 0):

This is the classic "producer consumer/reader writer" concurrency problem. There are several ways you can go about this - Some being slightly outdated however easier to understand for a beginner like yourself.

In order for 2 or more threads to be dependent on each other starting or finishing, there must be a concept of a shared object or variable which can be changed by each thread, to signal the other threads that the current one is finished. It is important that only one thread is changing the shared object at any one time (Also known as the critical section). In this case, you could use some Java 8 concurrency features to synchronise these 2 threads. Heres a simple example below using some Java 8 Concurrency syntax, namely the ReadWriteLock, which has been created especially for this use case.

```
public class ReaderWriterProblem {

   private ReentrantReadWriteLock theLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(true);

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ReaderWriterProblem rwProblem = new ReaderWriterProblem();
      Reader reader1 = new Reader(theLock);
      Writer writer1 = new Writer(theLock);

      new Thread(reader1).start();
      new Thread(writer1).start();
   }

   private class Reader implements Runnable {
    private ReentrantReadWriteLock theLock;

    public Reader(ReentrantReadWriteLock theLock) {
         this.theLock = theLock;
      }

      public void run() {

         try {
            theLock.readLock().lock();
            System.out.println("Currently Reading!");
            try {
               Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
         } finally {
            theLock.readLock().unlock();
         }
      }
   }

   private class Writer implements Runnable {

    private ReentrantReadWriteLock theLock;

    public Writer(ReentrantReadWriteLock theLock) {
         this.theLock = theLock
      }

      public void run() {
         try {
            theLock.writeLock().lock();
            System.out.println("Currently Writing!");
            try {
               Thread.sleep(4000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
         } finally {
            theLock.writeLock().unlock();
         }

      }
   }
}
```

This is a very basic example but the ReadWriteLock actually comes with built in support for one writer at any time and many readers. So when a thread holds the write Lock, no other thread can write at the same time, however several threads can hold the read lock at one time.

Other potential solutions to this problem include semaphores and busy wait, which are worth having a look at online.

SHORT ANSWER to why your question was wrong - You need to synchronise shared objects and variables, not the instances of classes that are executing the concurrent statements. Hope this helps you understand a little more. Notice how the lock is shared between the reader and writer.